# EF Linq Product Sum when no records returned

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I’ve seen variations of this question all over the place but none of the answers work for me.  Most of them are just trying to sum a single column too – nothing more complex such as the sum of a product as below:

```
public double Total

    {
        get
        {
            return _Context.Sales.Where(t => t.Quantity > 0)
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
                .Sum(t => t.Quantity * t.Price);                 
        }
    }
```

If no rows are returned I want to return zero.  However if no rows are returned the .Sum() fails. There are various options of trying to insert Convert.ToDouble and using null coalesce operators, but they all still gave me errors.

I’m sure I am missing a simple way to do this – any help greatly appreciated after too long banging head against google brick wall!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove `DefaultIfEmpty()` operator. Cast `Sum` result to nullable type. Then use null-coalescing operator to return default value if query returned `null`

```
public double Total    
{
   get
   {
       return _Context.Sales
                      .Where(t => t.Quantity > 0)
                      .Sum(t => (double?)(t.Quantity * t.Price)) ?? 0; 
   }
}
```

Generated SQL will look like:

```
SELECT SUM([Filter1].[A1]) FROM 
(SELECT CAST(CAST([Extent1].[Quantity] AS decimal(19,0)) * 
                  [Extent1].[Price] AS float) AS [A1]
 FROM [dbo].[Sales] AS [Extent1]
 WHERE [Extent1].[Quantity] > 0) AS Filter1
```

Comment: Thanks @lazyberezovsky.  Have tried that - receive a compiler error: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'int'.  But this is exactly what I'm trying to acheive...

Comment: @user1622713 I think casting to nullable type will help you

Comment: @lazyberezovsky doesn't `Sum` return zero not `null` if the sequence is empty?

Comment: @alexw nope, L2E returns null in this case

Comment: @lazyberezovsky if L2E returns null then `Sum` will throw an exception. I think he will need to check for any rows before calling `Sum`

Comment: @alexw just verified - `Sum` throws and exception if expected result is non-nullable. So, casting should be done in `Sum` operator to force usage of expression `Sum<Expression<Func<Sale, double?>>` with nullable result.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Yes that's it nice one.  I swear I went down that path a while ago and I must have simply had brackets out of whack!  Cheers, I can now get on with my life.